# The use of all in "It's all your fault"

Tags: word-usage, sentence-structure

When I type this sentence in Ms Word. "It's all your fault". It is underlined in green. The reason being given is that "all" is used with plural nouns. Instead entire is recommended as a correction.
But when I searched the Internet I have found the sentences like "It's all my fault or It's all your fault."

I would like to know if this sentence [It's all your fault] is idiomatic? If yes then why Ms word is showing it as incorrect?

Comment: See my answer for the grammar -- do you understand it?

Comment: @BillJ I have read your answer. As far as I can understand from your comment is that all is basically an extra info and is related to "all" not "your fault"

Comment: So entirely can replace it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ms word is not a reliable indicator of anything about grammar.

This sense of *all* means the same as *entirely*:
[American Heritage Dictionary *all*](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=all)
adv.1. a. Wholly; completely

*It's all your fault.* is entirely idiomatic, common, and unremarkable.

Answer (score 0):

> *It's all your fault.*

Yes, it's idiomatic and very commonly heard.

The grammar is interesting.

The entirety meaning doesn’t apply to "your fault" but to "it": "all your fault" is not here a noun phrase, not a single constituent. The "all" is an adjunct and the noun phrase is just "your fault".

The meaning can be glossed as "It is entirely your fault".

Now you know!